why nil is valid for any but not [T any]?
from Return default value for generic type

You can't return nil for any type. If int is used as the type argument for T for example, returning nil makes no sense

ain't these two statements contradictory.
if nil is valid for any, it should be for [T any]. T will always be any.
is int not any? if not how does [T any] works?

Nil would not be valid for any type, like in the Argument, for int nil would make no sense. Pretty good explained in the Post ;)

nil is valid for the any type but not for any type. int is an example of a type that cannot be nil. "T will always be any" is just wrong. T is constrained by any. It could be any, int or map[float]string.

any can be used as a static type or (because it's an interface type) as a type constraint.
When it's used as a static type — i.e. the type of a variable, a function parameter, etc. — it can be assigned the value nil just like any other interface.

[x can be assigned to a variable of type T if] x is the predeclared identifier nil and T is a pointer, function, slice, map, channel, or interface type, but not a type parameter.

When it's used as a type constraint, it is constraining what types can instantiate a type parameter. There is no identity relationship with the type parameter itself. It's saying: "this T can be anything that satisfies any".
When you write:
func Foo[T any]() {
    var t T
    // ...
}

the variable t has precisely type T. It does not have type any, because any was not used as a static type. The rules about assignment cover this case specifically:

[x can be assigned to a variable of type T if] x is the predeclared identifier nil, T is a type parameter, and x is assignable to each type in T's type set.

In the above function, T's type set is determined by it's constraint any. All types can satisfy any as a constraint, including, for example, int and string. You cannot assign nil to those types, therefore you can't assign nil to a variable of type T.
Imagine to instantiate the function Foo with int, you can immediately see why assigning nil won't compile. Substitute each time T appears in the function body with int:
// instantiate T with int
func Foo() {
    var t int
    t = nil // obviously cannot work
}


If there is an interface x which is used like [T x], then also same error will be thrown since value type can also implement interface x. but nil is invalid for them, as they are not pointers.
generics will make sure whatever T is, it implements interface x. But issue arises due to interfaces supporting both value types as well as pointer types, but nil being only valid for pointers. any is just interface{}, so same.
